# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8/3'

Tags: python, input, type-conversion

I am having the folllowing instruction

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,xp,yp = map(float, input().split())
```

When I am trying to execute it for a fractional value, e.g. 8/3, I get an error message.

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,xp,yp = map(float, input().split())
0.1 0.2 -8 -16.67 0 0.1 8/3 1
# output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,xp,yp = map(float, input().split())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8/3'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8/3` is not a valid notation for a python float. However, you can parse these inputs using the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> inp = '0.1 0.2 8/3 1/2 -5/10'
>>> [float(fractions.Fraction(s)) for s in inp.split()]
[0.1, 0.2, 2.6666666666666665, 0.5, -0.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The string `8/3` can't be converted using `float`, just use something from `fractions` module.